# How to gatherElementById starting with a specific word?

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous, prototypejs

Using Prototype and Script.aculo.us, I am trying to make all tags with an ID starting with "idea" [Droppable](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/script.aculo.us/scriptaculous_drag_drop.htm) but I can't remember how to get all tags starting with a specific string.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: More information please.  Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for info on how to write good questions.  Posting code samples, and telling us more about what you are trying to do, is the best way to get a good, quality answer

Comment: What is "gatherElementById".  You really need to make this question more clear.

Comment: I think Javascript needs more synonyms in its function names. Perhaps retriveElementById, fetchElementById, acquireElementById etc.

Comment: Is it so hard to understand? I added the frameworks to the question and rephrased it slightly. Todd, please let me know if that is what you meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them a class and do $$('div.idea');

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers are correct, use a class name instead.

However if you are forced to use IDs there is a way with a CSS selector, now [supported](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) by most JS frameworks:

```
$$('*[id^=idea]')
```

Comment: you were the innovator of this code and I did experiment and found it not working. After adding a little flavor, I made it working. However, all credits should be to you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. IDs are meant to be used to get a single element.

The proper way to do what you want is giving those elements a common *class*. Then you can use whatever method prototype has to retrieve all elements with that class name (in jQuery it would be `$('.class')`). By using classes you allow your JS framework to use highly optimized code to search for matching elements (might even be a native `getElementsByClassName` method) instead of iterating over basically every single element and doing a substring comparison.

Edit: In prototype you can use `$$('.class')` to get all matching elements.